# How to query for elements in a collection in Spring Mongo JPA

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-jpa, spring-mongo

I'm using JPA repositories and I see they all have findBy methods. How can I do the equivalent of SQL IN clause e.g. findAll(where field in 'a','b','c')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findByFieldNameIn(List<String> fieldList);`

This should work fine.

You can refer  this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords) to learn to build repository methods.